# How does str.replace() method work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this input:

```
'0472/91.39.17'
```

I want to replace my input with `'1234567890'` one by one like this:

```
'1234/56.78.90'
```

But my outcome is

```
0472/91.09.17
```

Here's my code

```
phone = '0472/91.39.17'
repl = 1234567890

for i in phone:
    if i.isdigit():
        for j in str(repl):
            x = phone.replace(i, j)
        print(x)
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: If your outcome is always the samething, why do you need to implement a logic. Hard-code it has `'1234/56.78.90'`.

Comment: Why are you iterating through repl? You just want to replace i by repl[i]

Comment: @OmarHaque that won't work, because `i` is not an index. Even if it were an index, it wouldn't match up with the "next character" each time.

Comment: `repl = 1234567890` assigns an integer to it, not a string.

Comment: @martineau yeah he later casts it to `str`, I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn `repl` into an iterator and use a generator expression to replace any value in `phone` with the next value in the repl iter if the original value is a digit. Re-combine that together with `''.join` to get a string as a result, and Bob's your uncle.

```
repliter = iter(str(repl))

result = ''.join(next(repliter) if c.isdigit() else c for c in phone)
# the ternary expression here evaluates to:
# if c.isdigit():
#     next(repliter)
# else:
#     c
```

Note that this will crash with a `StopIteration` error if your phone number contains more than 10 digits, so consider using `itertools.cycle` for `repliter` instead.

```
import itertools

repliter = itertools.cycle(str(repl)) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 ...
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a try catch to get rid of errors

Comment: With "except StopIteration"

Comment: @AustinA you mean try except? There is no `catch` in Python. However that won't give you any sort of expected result, it'll just safely exit. If you wanted to do that you could use the optional argument in `next`. `next(repliter, 0)`

Comment: Right, that's better.

Comment: @AustinA except for very long numbers it'll look more than a little odd. `0118 999 881 999 119 725 3` becomes `1234 567 890 000 000 000 0` rather than `1234 567 890 123 456 789 0`.

Comment: and, since I'm working on Haskell, here's a [solution using that.](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0ffaa4b2b6d77e148c3953f4d7a4c8e2)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking you could use itertools count with modulus for numbers higher than 10.

```
from itertools import count

c = count(0) # start number
phone = '0472/91.39.17'

''.join(str(next(c) % 10) if item.isdigit() else item for item in phone)
```